# What's the point of security if we use javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question is quite simple. I did an API with basic Authentication, secrets that you have to send as request param, etc...

Now the front-end team from my company decided that it's a good idea to just  but code with the basicAuth as Base64 in the code:

```
var data = {
            username: username,
            password: userpassword
        };

 "Authorization": "Basic bWVsbsafasfcGFzc3dvcmQ=",
```

If u just go to the network, you can see everything....

**Isn't there a way to create a javascript file with API configs and hide it from the user??**

Comment: ooooff. So many reasons. For your case you would probably want to hash the passwords before they are sent to the server. Then if the server database gets hacked, then its just the hashed password that gets leaked.

Comment: Always use encrypted connections (https) and server-side authentication. For the session-cookies that indicates the session use hashing or unique non-identifiable values to connect the client- and server-side sessions.